# Subgroup of a locally compact group with uncountably many laterals.

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, harmonic-analysis

Does there exist a locally compact, Hausdorff, non-discrete topological group $G$ with the following properties?

- There exists $H \leq G$ proper clopen subgroup;
- $G / H$ is an uncountable set.

Comment: For a locally compact group, the itemized condition (I first wrote "the two itemized condition", but it's a single condition since the second item is senseless without reference to the first one: the correct wording should be "there exists $H\le G$ open subgroup such that $G/H$ is uncountable) is equivalent to the condition of $G$ not being $\sigma$-compact. So the question is just whether non-$\sigma$-compact fails to imply discrete, and the answer is obviously yes (it does not imply discrete), and I agree that @Taroccoesbrocco's question is what I'd have liked to ask before giving an answer.

Comment: PS I guess "lateral" is a literal translation from another language, but the English terminology is rather "coset".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $K$ any uncountable discrete group (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ with discrete topology) and $H$ any locally compact Hausdorff non-discrete group (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ with Euclidean topology). Then $G=K\times H$ seems to satisfy your conditions.